# How to horizontally center a floating element of a variable width?

Tags: css, css-float, positioning, centering, variable-width

How to horizontally center a floating element of a variable width?

Edit: I already have this working using a containing `div` for the floating element and specifying a `width` for the container (then use `margin: 0 auto;` for the container). I just wanted to know whether it can be done without using a containing element or at least without having to specify a `width` for the containing element.

Comment: If you're going to center it, why is it floated?

Comment: it's a long story, I'm floating it for other reasons

Comment: possible duplicate of [**How to center float elements?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-to-center-float-elements)

Answer (score 92):

Assuming the element which is floated and will be centered is a `div` with an `id="content"`
...

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="content">
   This will be centered
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And apply the following **CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Here is a good [reference](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing#Centering_Floats) regarding that.

Comment: You can also try `margin-left` instead of `left` and `position: relative`.  Margin-left worked for me on the -50% element.

Comment: yea - but what is the added value @muhd?

Comment: @marcusklaas, the added value is that it may work in cases where the posted solution does not, or may be easier to implement.  I don't remember much about this since it was a month ago.

Comment: I dig the solution, but you might need overflow-x: hidden to prevent horizontal scrollbars.  That took a bit to figure out.

Comment: Link to "reference" appears dead.

Answer (score 76):

```
.center {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: this worked out much better for me than the accepted answer, try both!

Comment: I prefer this method better as well, but it works on IE8+ so if you need IE7 you should use the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks-  saved my time, really!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `fit-content` value for `width`.

```
#wrap {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;   
}
```

Note: It works only in latest browsers.

Answer (score 5):

This works better when the id = container (which is the outer div) and id = contained (which is the inner div). The problem with the highly recommended solution is that it results in some cases into an horizontal scrolling bar when the browser is trying to cater for the left: -50% attribute. [There is a good reference](http://benohead.com/css-center-variable-width-divs-horizontally/) for this solution

```
        #container {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #contained {
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

Comment: This actually worked great. The combination of `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a `DIV` you want centred horizontally:

```
 <div id="foo">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

In the CSS you'd style it with this:

```
#foo
{
  margin:0 auto; 
  width:30%;
}
```

Which states that you have a top and bottom margin of zero pixels, and on either left or right, automatically work out how much is needed to be even.

Doesn't really matter what you put in for the width, as long as it's there and isn't 100%. Otherwise you wouldn't be setting the centre on anything.

But if you float it, left or right, then the bets are off since that pulls it out of the normal flow of elements on the page and the auto margin setting won't work.

Comment: The only issue here is that you have to explicitly set the width; `width: auto;` doesn't work (AFAIK).

Comment: Correct, you do have to set something as the width. But the question was asking about variable width, hopefully that's not another word for auto and instead some fluctuating value or relative amount, like em's or %

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I don't have a problem with centering elements, what I'm trying to do is center a "floating element". I know this is not possible in CSS but was hoping somebody might have a hack that can work for this, I even tried to use a table but that didn't work too. Unfortunately in my scenario there's no way to make the element not floating, I need this for specific reasons.

Answer (score 4):

The popular answer here does work sometimes, but other times it creates horizontal scroll bars that are tough to deal with - especially when dealing with wide horizontal navigations and large pull down menus. Here is an even lighter-weight version that helps avoid those edge cases:

```
#wrap {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
#content {
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Proof that it is working!**](http://jsfiddle.net/sapioit/b423z/1/)

To more specifically answer your question, it is probably not possible to do without setting up some containing element, however it is very possible to do without specifying a width value. Hope that saves someone out there some headaches!

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use `display: inline block` and `align` to `center`?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaikemono/cwx8z/).

Comment: `inline-block` good solution! at least you got +1 after 7 years ;)

Comment: This is what worked good for me, thank you!

Comment: `inline-block` +1 after 12 years!

Answer (score 0):

for 50% element

```
width: 50%;
display: block;
float: right;
margin-right: 25%;
```