# Left justify centered text in tds

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a report that's displayed in a table, the text inside tds must be centered but left justified, how can I accomplish that ?

```
<td style="text-align: center;"><?=$row['column']?></td>
```

Comment: Are you try to achieve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702802/how-can-i-centre-left-aligned-text-even-when-it-wraps

Comment: I'm limited to using tables, so divs only wont work for me, thanks anyway

Comment: How can text be centered *and* left-justified?

Comment: @DavidThomas He means the text block being centered and the text inside left-justified.

Comment: @Digitalfortress Can you use divs inside tables? If so you can center the div and keep the inner text left-justified.

Comment: What! `center left-justified`, what does that mean ?

Comment: @Antony Yea you got me right, do you mean I put on td align=left then contain text inside divs and put align=center on div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contain the text in a `div` and center it in the `td` like this:

HTML

```html
<td><div class="inner">left justified text in a centered block</div></td>
```

CSS

```css
.inner {
    width: 20%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3p2b/1/)

You don't have to specify `align=left` in the div. It is aligned left by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to modify the mark-up, the only option I can suggest is to use `padding`:

```
 td {
    width: 7em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3VThf/).

This will place the text `1em` away from the left and right boundaries of the cell, but retain left-justification within those boundaries.

Remember that padding will be *added* to the `width` of the cell, though, so with the above the dimensions of the cell will be `width` + `padding-left` + `padding-right` + `border-left` + `border-right`, so: (`7em + 1em + 1em + 1px + 1px`). To contain the `padding` and `border`s *within* the defined `width` you can use `box-sizing` in compliant browsers:

```
 td {
    width: 7em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 1em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3VThf/1/).

Comment: This is a good way of achieving it, but if the table width is 100%, and it expands with screen resolution, the text wont be centered inside tables, right ?

Comment: I dont know the table width, it's set to 100%, so everytime the screen size changes, table width would change, I need to make sure its always centered

Comment: This will be centered within the cell. If there are constraints on your table, or the cells, please add that to the question. And explain clearly, show images if they'll help. As it is, I don't understand what you're asking in your comment: the size of the `table` has nothing to do with the centering of the text in the `td`. It might not be legible if the cells are too small, but the browser will still do its best to position it appropriately within the constraints of the CSS.