# Centering text in html while keeping it left justified?

Tags: html, css, text

I've looked through many posts on this topic but the traditional solutions don't seem to be working.  I'm most likely doing something wrong but I can't see what.  I'm trying to center the text within a div while keeping it left justified.  Here is my code/markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="title">
        Hi, I'm <a href="#">name</a>.  This is some of my <a href="#">work</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home {
    padding: 120px 75px 0px 75px;
    margin: 0 0 200px 0;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
   .title {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   color: var(--text-primary);
}
```

At the moment I have it set up so the text within the title div is left justified, and the title div is centered within the home div (at least I think that's what's going on.)  I've also tried flex box, but to no avail.  I think the issue has to do with the fact that the text in the h1 tag wraps, leaving space on the right side (selected in red below).  Here is what I mean:

[image]

Thank you for looking, I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Try an extra wrapper inside title, and set display:flex; justify-content: center; on .title;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Center block, but align contents to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269589/css-center-block-but-align-contents-to-the-left)

Comment: PythonMaster202 I looked at that and tried to replicate it but it didn't work.  Thank you for the comment though.

Comment: @SeanDoherty I tried that but no dice, text is still not centered.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can you build a codepen? Because I copied your code and it kind of works anyway, but looks nothing like your example - so i think there are conflicting styles from elsewhere?

Comment: Sure, here you go.  Thank you for looking.  (i've made a few changes based on other people's suggestions but the problem still persists.) https://codepen.io/roadrunner645/pen/BaowNOg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by "shrink-wrapping" the title div to the text that is inside, so that the text was centered within it, and then use the home div as a flex box within which the title div was centered.

```
.home {
    padding: 5% 0;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 5.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: var(--text-primary);
}

.title {
    width: max-content;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else having this problem!

Answer (score 0):

> I think u need this.

```css
.home {
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0 0 200px 0;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background:red;
}
.title {
   display: inline-block;
   color: var(--text-primary);
   background: yellow;
   width: calc(100% - 100px);
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <div class="title">
        Hi, I'm <a href="#">name</a>.  This is some of my <a href="#">work</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried that but still have the same problem.  The div in which the text resides is centered, but the text itself is not.

Comment: Edited. See now ... & let me know that is okey or not. There is  another way.  @TheRedTopHat

Comment: Unfortunately the same thinkg happens.  The div red div is centered, and the yellow div is centered within that, but the text is not centered within the div.

Comment: But it is looking center

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I usually try this when i want to center anything so i hope it works with you.

```css
.home{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving "home" width:100% and to "title" margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto