# how to center an inline div using css?

Tags: css, html, center

How can I center an inline div (not its content) using css?

VERY IMPORTANT: the width of the div is unknown (I can not specify it)

Comment: You're not crazy, they seriously missed something in the CSS (2&3) spec on this one, when the `<center>` tag was deprecated a style rule should have been added to replace it immediately.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to do this or is CSS still broken?

Answer (score 21):

If by inline you mean, its CSS display property is set to `inline` then you can center it by giving the immediate parent container a `text-align:center`

If you mean a div within another div, you can follow this approach if you can add a wrapper and float both:

[How to horizontally center a floating element of a variable width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232096/how-to-horizonatally-center-a-floating-element-of-a-variable-width)

Comment: If the intent is to set it to `inline`...why use a `<div>`? It seems like this solution wouldn't work in 99% of cases, since you're completely changing the layout by doing this.

Comment: its not working. if I set on the container text-align:center, my div's content get centered even if I overwrite on my div the text-align style.

Comment: @Nick: agree setting a block element to inline is a bit pointless, but that's what the Mihai seems to be asking.

Comment: @Mihai: Check the specificity of your CSS for the div and its content. Make it more specific by using an ID or more selectors and the div's content should not be centered. If that doesn't work, use `text-align:left !important;`

Comment: I have something like this: <div inline> <img1> text <br/> <img2> some longer text <br/> <img3> some longer longer text </div>. All i want is to center my div on the page with all the images one under another and the text on the right. The images are some small icons. I made the div inline only not to spread it across the whole width of the page :(

Comment: @Mihai: the code didn't come through in your last comment. use the '`' characters around your code or just add it to the question

Comment: and the problem is the the contet is centered and the images at the beginning of the lines are not one under the other anymore

Comment: @Mihai: I think you need to rethink the markup and approach to layouting this with CSS. Can you post a screenshot of what you have now and what the desired result is?

Comment: Also from what I understand, I think you are better off wrapping each icon / text in one container. In fact what you're describing sounds very much like a list. Have you looked at using a `<ul>` and using your image icons for the bullets?

Comment: I'll try it as a list. But I have to put the image in list item because are different images. Thank you for your effort guys.

Comment: u can give each `<li>` a different class and use the different icons

Comment: I know. But I hate using background-image on li when is more natural to use list-style-image on ul. And I have to wrap the icons as links, so there must go in the list item. Thank you again.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this.
You should add new `div` with `text-align:center` outside your `div`like this

`<div style="text-align:center;"> <div>`

which not in center with inline display `</div></div>`

Comment: This solution worked for me when trying to center an iframe from Giphypress in Wordpress. Good stuff!

Answer (score 7):

This is the easiest and most straightforward solution

```
.center {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: doesn't fit for more than one div - because if there will be multiple lines of divs, the second line will start to align from where previous was - if param float:left, then to left and a lot of space will be on the right side - It will be not centered.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it into a div that you can specify the width of and then set the margins of the div in question to: margin: 0, auto;

Comment: because this approach only works for block elements. inline elements do not get a specified width.

Comment: This works always, you need to block it. display:block;width:200px;margin:0 auto 0 auto;

Answer (score 2):

you can probably get away with `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center;` on the parent element if you want it it to be "blocky". also you'll probably need to give it a `vertical-align:top`