# Why does my site look different when it is previewed in Dreamweaver compared to when it is published?

Tags: html, css, adobe, dreamweaver

When I compare the mobile version of my site in Dreamweaver to the actual site when it is live, they both look incredibly different. The code is the exact same and I'm using the same browser with the same settings. You can see the clear differences between the two here:

In Dreamweaver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ39p.jpg

Live: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDCuW.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it would be great if you could share the code, so we can give you a solution. You can also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408612/dreamweaver-design-and-live-view-show-different-things, its apparently a known issue. Thus the Dreamweaver preview shouldnt be your main monitor of css changes.

Comment: Upvoting @Niklas specifically for "_Dreamweaver preview shouldn't be your main monitor of css changes_" **Chrome Developer Tools** or **Firefox Developer Edition** are much more accurate at depicting what you will see on your live mobile site

Comment: @Niklas Thanks very much for the suggestions! I will be sure to take a look at the link. I just viewed the local document straight in Chrome without using Dreamweaver's preview and it also displayed weirdly so it is clearly an issue with Dreamweaver's preview at this point.

Comment: @Niklas it turns out the issue was caused by me not including '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by me not including the following code in the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```