# align li menu items center

Tags: html, css

i have this css code for my responsive css menu:

```
nav, ul, li, a {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
     background:#f36f25;
}
.nav:before,.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #1d7a62;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}
.nav li li li a {
    background:#249578;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav li li .parent {
        background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
   .nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

but i cannot get the menu items to align in the centre of the menu/page

here is a fiddle with the full code:

*http://jsfiddle.net/5Z2QV/*

Comment: you want list to be vertically center or horizontally?

Comment: Fix your jsFiddle. It's throwing exceptions on the console.

Comment: its a responsive menu so it will be horizontal then when the screen gets too small it will change to vertical

Comment: Take a look here perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements

Comment: fiddle is not working to see menu items..

Answer (score 2):

Is **[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Z2QV/6/)** what you want?
If so, then you have to remove `float` from the `li`s and add `display: inline-block` to them. Then you have to add `text-align: center` to the `.nav`

```
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    background:#f36f25;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I also removed `border-top` from the `li` and put it in the `.nav` to remove the gaps between `li`s.

**EDIT**:
To keep sub-menu items aligned to the left, add this CSS:

```
.nav li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

**EDIT2**:

You don't need this `adjustMenu()` javascript function. You can use `media queries`. Modify your `@media` section a bit. Add this style:

```
.nav {
    border-top: none;
}
```

and replace style for `.nav > li` with this:

```
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
```

Also, I noticed that in the small range of resolution, one menu item breaks into new line. To prevent this, you can add this style to the `.nav`

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Here's the update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z2QV/9/

Comment: YES! someone who understands :) thank you. is there any way it can be how it is but with the sub menu items still aligned left and not centre?

Comment: when the page width gets smaller, the menu items all align under each other. when i use your css they dont

Comment: See my edit. It resolves the problem with left alignment in sub-menus. Now I'll try to fix your responsive menu.

Comment: perfect thanks :) i don't suppose you know how to add background colour on hover and active on the main links? i have tried on a few of the CSS elements but can't get it working

Comment: @charlie, you can try with `.nav > li:hover { background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center; }` ?