# CSS menu isn't centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built this menu: 
**[JSBIN EDIT](http://jsbin.com/cayob/1) ; [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cayob/1)** 
As you see, the menu isn't centered at the middle of the bar, he's centered up. However, I want to make it go lower, exactly at the middle. 
So, I had an idea to do `margin-top: 26px` because the bar's height is 53 pixels, but it doesn't change anything. I also did `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align:center`. 
I read this [**STACKOVERFLOW**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements) and realized that it is related in float, but I don't want to float it - I want to make it go down.
Thank you!

Comment: About the "**update**": This is *not* how SO works. If a user has answered your question, accept it. If you have a NEW problem, open/create a new question, and not add on to the pre-existing one.

Comment: Write the link of the question you just removed from here I have its answer

Comment: @KID here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797746/css-image-causes-problems-in-menu Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You need to give the line height by using `line-height`.</strike> Okay, **updated**, the `line-height` trick doesn't work!!! And also, giving this to the `<a>` tag does the trick:

```
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/cayob/2

Comment: Thanks, works! But I have another request, I accordingly updated my post. Thanks again.

Comment: @rolory Another request belongs to another question. If Praveen answer worked, you have to accept it.

+1 for the very simple and ingenious fix, Praveen!

Comment: @rolory Please accept this answer, and post a new question for the new issue. You may add the new question's link to this comment. :)

Comment: I saw that. Sure, waiting to answer your challenging question! :P

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` of the links to the height of the bar, in this example 53 pixels.