# CSS Image causes problems in menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/cayob/2) menu code.
I have been trying to put a picture at the middle of the menu, like that [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/cayob/4) code. 
But there are two problems:

- The distance from the left menu ("About Us") to the edge and the distance from the right menu ("Swap Guides") are different.
- The image lowers the menu down.

I tried to use the `line-height` setting and tried to play with the position of the image, but it isn't helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.navgroups li {
   float:left;
   list-style:none;
}
```

Here is the **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cayob/7/edit)**
And remove display:inline from this.

Comment: Thanks for help! I've accepted it. But something last: what did you do there? I don't want to open another and another unnecessary question and if I understand why you did it, it might save for all of us.

Comment: Okay, I am not entirely sure, how to explain it but please take time and read about floats. The thing is unusual height of the image was somehow causing ul's height to increase more than it's parent. which caused the menu to move down.

Comment: I really have problems with floats, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hey, sorry to disturb again but the first problems with the edges still happening. I think that it's happening because of the float;left. What's wrong?

Comment: Let me check. What browser are you using ?

Comment: Try using 0 padding on ul.menu

Comment: I'm using Opera and Chrome, but mostly Opera. I think that it works. Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to keep this structure, You have to choose, because the right side content is not equal to the left side. You can try changing menu positions. For example Swap "swap guides" with "faq"

Comment: So it dependent on the number of letters in each sides? Which mean that if I want to make the sides equal, I need the same numbers of letters on the right and the left?

Comment: No entirely but since you are not defining li's width they take content's width. You can try defining li's width

Comment: It is very sensitive because if I change the li's width, the distance between them is grown and I want it will be the same, the same for <a> tag.. and by the way, thank you for your help. I'm very appreciate it. If I don't succeed, you still deserve an accept or vote-up. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `padding: 0` to your `.navgroups .menu`:

```
.navgroups .menu {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and change your `.navgroups li` to this:

```
.navgroups li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

**[Updated JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cayob/12)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem that the first problem is solved.