# HTML/CSS: How to center floating divs?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="boxContainer">
        <div id="box1">
            <span>Text1</span>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <span>Text2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
#container {
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#boxContainer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:black;
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    background-color:blue
}

#box2 {
    float: left;
    background-color:red
}
```

I expect the `#boxContainer`'s width to match the sum of width of `#box1` and `#box2`, but it is 100% and therefore it is not centered in the `#container`. Why?

I have this fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/dxbfpbg1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center float elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Block-level elements that are not floated (like your `#boxContainer` div) will default to 100% width. You can change it to `display: inline-block` to only take up the space that it needs. You can then center it with `text-align: center` on its parent element.

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow
}

#boxContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:black;
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    background-color:blue
}

#box2 {
    float: left;
    background-color:red
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxbfpbg1/2/

Comment: You have space under the two divs

Answer (score 4):

Because you use `floats`. One solution is to use `display: inline-block` and set `text-align: center` to the container:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow
}
#boxContainer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
#box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue
}
#box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="container">
  <div id="boxContainer">
    <div id="box1">
      <span>Text1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <span>Text2</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also to remove space you can set `font-size: 0` to parent container and set `font-size: Xpx` to child elements like:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 0;
}
#boxContainer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
#box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="container">
  <div id="boxContainer">
    <div id="box1"> <span>Text1</span>

    </div>
    <div id="box2"> <span>Text2</span>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat you by about 15 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

## `display: table`

You could use [`display: table` and `display: table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)) instead of `float` to achieve the result you're looking for. This has the benefit of not requiring any use of `clear` or having to use hacks to get rid of the space below `#box1` and `#box2`.

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow
}
#boxContainer {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: black;
}
#box1 {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: blue
}
#box2 {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="boxContainer">
    <div id="box1">
      <span>Text1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <span>Text2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## `display: inline-flex`

`display: table` has the downside of forcing `#box1` and `#box2` into columns, however. So, another option you have available is [`display: inline-flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)). This allows for wrapping `#box2` onto the next line when `#box1` is wide enough, however, it is also lacking the browser support that `display: table` has.

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
#boxContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: blue
}
#box2 {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="boxContainer">
    <div id="box1">
      <span>Text1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <span>Text2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```