# css -- put something to the left of a centered element?

Tags: css, alignment, centering

The picture shows what I want to achieve.  Can it be done?
[image]

For centering, without the putting something to the left part, see here: [How do I center float elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements)

Answer (score 5):

Yes! That can be achieved by absolute positioning, if you are careful about what you do.

First, the make a wrapper `<div>`, with the centered text `<div>`, containing a child (left-positioned) `<div>`.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='centered'>
        This text is horizontally centered.
        <div class='left'>
            This text is to the left of the centered text.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, set the `text-align` of the wrapper to `center`:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Set the centered text `display: inline-block` and `position: relative`:

```
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

And finally, position the left text absolute with `right: 100%`:

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyblalock/28q08auq/1/

Comment: Almost . . . the only problem is that the width of the "left" part is set to a "magic number" of 100px, rather than adjusting itself to the available space on the page.

Comment: As flexbox has gained more widespread adoption, this is also a good approach. See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/28q08auq/8/)