# How do I center the div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the div appear in center but it is always at the left side. I am using bootstrap for screen compatibility, so I didn't work with the adjusting of the left and right margins. What went wrong in the code?

Please help!

```
<div id="div1" 
style="display: inline-block; 
position: absolute; margin: 20px auto; 
width: 1140px; 
height: 442px; 
overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Welcome! A [codepen](http://codepen.io) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will go a long way to getting people into helping you! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center float elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `position: absolute;` and `display: inline-block` styles, and it'll work.

Comment: @user1023 For solely what you showed us, it works. You'll need to provoide more information if this doesn't work for you. Id est, can you tell us what it's for, its parent, and its children?

Comment: it's for an image slider.

Comment: @user1023 That doesn't help me figure out why it doesn't work for you. You'll need to provide more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/mkb8gy6g/

Remove `display:inline-block;` & `position:absolute;`

Comment: Can you provide more code so we can better judge your situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` values once you have applied `position: absolute`, it inherits from its parent or browser default will be applied. That is why you see your div is always in left. In this case what you could do is

1. You could align it using `top`, `left` and other attributs
2. you
   could remove position: absolute, make it `inline-block` and apply
   `text-align: center`

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

Use `text-align:center;` in your css

```
<div id="div1" 
style="display: inline-block; 
position: absolute; margin: 20px auto; 
width: 1140px; 
text-align:center;
height: 442px; 
overflow: hidden;"> Test </div>
```

Comment: This will only center `inline` elements *inside* the div, not the div itself.

Comment: @user10 Hi. It is an image container. 
Text-align property didn't work.