# Make the div centered align

Tags: html, css

i have 10 DIVs and all of them are set FLOAT:LEFT property.
I need to make all DIVs float from center.
eg.
[image]

Please check my code: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqrGVO)

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child >  div
{
  float:left;
  height:100px;width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;

}.child{
  border:1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: "I need to make all DIVs float from center." - I don't get what you are asking for. Please post an image of what your desired result looks like. Do you mean "centered" rather than "float from center"?

Comment: I have posted a image

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements

Answer (score 1):

```
.child >  div
{
  display: inline-block;
  height:100px;width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOKNoe

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this css to `child` to make child center. If you want `child`'s inner div center also remove `float`

```
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPrbgJ)

Answer (score 0):

Hej, you should consider to wrap them in rows ant to center the wrappers with `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no float: center; - floating is either left or right. You can achieve what you need by simply making your inner divs `display: inline-block;` and removing the float rule. 
Working solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOZdoN

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your quick responses.
I got what i wanted.

```css
.child >  div
{
  display: inline-block;
  height:100px;width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  
}.child{
  border:1px solid green;
  display:table-cell;
  width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
 
}
.main{
  display:table;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```