# Tricky horizontal center in css : floating elements only

Tags: html, css

I can't find a way to properly align a button in the middle of floating elements.

```css
button {
  float:left;
}


header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
}

header a, header label {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}

header a:hover, header label:hover { color: #aaa; }

header label {
  float: right;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header label:after {
  content: "\2261";
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
  
nav {
  float: right;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s; 
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
       -o-transition: max-height 0.3s;
          transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
  
nav li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
  
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav { display: none; }

#nav:checked ~ nav {
  max-height: 200px; /* This can be anything bigger than your nav height. The transition duration works with this */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  
  header label { display: none; }
  
  nav {
    width: auto;
    max-height: none;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  
  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  header nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: auto;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<header>

  <a class="logo" href="http://minimaldev.com">Minimal Menu</a>
  
  <input id="nav" type="checkbox">
  <label for="nav"></label>
  
  <button>centered button ?</button>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 

</header>
```

See example also on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOKbWg)

I tried the display-table trick, but it breaks the navbar behaviour on small device (responsive).

I also tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508512) , but I have the same problem.

Any idea ? I thought about using calc(), but I can't find the right formula.

Comment: Do you really need the `float: left` on `button`? Have you tried the `transform` trick?

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to center the button, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

I made a couple of edits:

- added `text-align: center` to the parent element of the button
- bumped the button off the top edge with manual pixel adjustments (assuming the design stays rigid in terms of logo size, it is not a responsive solution because of the non-responsive nature of font and padding sizing).

Here it is in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/WQyWPP)

HTML:

```
<header>

  <a class="logo" href="http://minimaldev.com">Minimal Menu</a>

  <input id="nav" type="checkbox">
  <label for="nav"></label>

  <button>centered button</button>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav> 

</header>
```

CSS:

```
button{
  margin-top: 18px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
}

header a, header label {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}

header a:hover, header label:hover { color: #aaa; }

header label {
  float: right;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header label:after {
  content: "\2261";
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s; 
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
       -o-transition: max-height 0.3s;
          transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav { display: none; }

#nav:checked ~ nav {
  max-height: 200px; /* This can be anything bigger than your nav height. The transition duration works with this */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

  header label { display: none; }

  nav {
    width: auto;
    max-height: none;
  }

  nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  header nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: auto;
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer would have been so much better if it also handled the hamburger properly...

Comment: Nice effort, still a little bugged on responsive mode : the button moves when you click on the hamburger. +1 for the nice try.

Comment: I changed the vertical alignment to make it relative to the top of the header so the button wouldn't jump down in the case of the hamburger menu. Otherwise it's still just `text-align: center` in the parent that does the trick horizontally.