# Text-align for elements

Tags: html, css

I want to get a result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Kc2m/, but I don't want to use `text-align` for obvious reasons. I was trying to leave just `margin: 0 auto`, but it mysteriously doesn't work. So, how can I achieve this without `text-align` and `center`? And if you can, please let me know the reasons why it doesn't work with `margin: 0 auto` and why it works with yours, thank you.

When I tried with `float: left`, it didn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you specify a width on your `margin:0 auto` element.

It works in the fiddle because its an inline-block element, in conjuction with the text-align, but a block level element will span the entire width of the page if a width isnt specified, making the margin trick invalid.

Comment: What if I don't know the width?

Comment: And by specify a width I dont mean 100%, I mean a hard pixel width  which is as little as possible needed will span the contents of what you want to be centered.

Comment: Well, you can either choose a hard width, then resize the image or content inside to fit it, OR, you can look at centering elements when their floated by using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232096/how-to-horizonatally-center-a-floating-element-of-a-variable-width